# pygame.draw.Rect takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, pygame, rectangles, traceback

When I look at the Pygame docs for [`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect), it says that I can specify a keyword argument called `border_radius`, an integer used to round corners when drawing a rectangle. However, when I run the program with this line: `pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), my_rect, 2, border_radius=5)`, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 76, in <module>
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), rect, 2, border_radius=5)
TypeError: rect() takes no keyword arguments
```

Also, if I try `pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), my_rect, 2, 5)` without using keyword arguments, it throws another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 76, in <module>
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), rect, 2, 5)
TypeError: function takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank You in advance!

Comment: Does your installed pygame version match the documented version?

Comment: One issue could be how you imported pygame. Did you use `import pygame` or `from pygame import *`?

Comment: I used `import pygame`. What difference does it make, though. The method called is the same, right?

Comment: @KrishnanShankar If you used the latter, then you should do `draw.rect(...)`. There is a difference. Anyways, I wouldn't recommend using `from pygame import *`.

Comment: @TheMaker, Yes, I know that if I use `from pygame import *`, I will have to use `draw.rect()` instead of `pygame.draw.rect()`, because I am importing the modules from pygame instead of pygame itself. But I am pretty sure that the same method is being called both ways. As in, both calls would result in the same output. So, there really isn't a difference between `import pygame` `pygame.draw.rect()`, and `from pygame import *` `draw.rect()`, right? That was my original question.

Comment: Yes @KrishnanShankar. But if you call `from pygame import *`, and use `pygame.draw.rect()`, you will get an error. That is why I asked you whether you used `from pygame import *` or `import pygame`.

Comment: Oh, @TheMaker, that makes more sense. But wouldn't that throw a `NameError: pygame undefined` (or something like that) and not a `TypeError`?

Comment: @KrishnanShankar Yes, but I just wanted to make sure. One time I defined a `draw` class, and it had a rect attribute. I got a `NameError` before I realised what I did wrong.

Comment: Ok @TheMaker, thanks!

Comment: @KrishnanShankar I ran into this and had to do it myself a while ago. This question has been closed because it is a dup so I cannot add it here, but I just added the code I wrote to do it (as well as to do a rounded bordered rect as an answer to the question this now points to. 
Try the routines I wrote in that answer. The routines I wrote use anti-aliased circles because they look pretty jagged otherwise.